# Тире перед "это"?

Tags: пунктуация

*В методике Выготского – Сахарова это цвет, форма, высота и размер фигур. В методике Брунера это количество рамочек на карточке, количество фигур, их форма и цвет.*
[**Функциональность значений**](https://studme.org/43568/psihologiya/funktsionalnost_znacheniy)

Нужно ли тире перед "это"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

По грамматике предложения тире не нужно, так как местоимение "это" является подлежащим.

Но  возможно авторское тире, обозначающее паузу, связанную с параллельной структурой текста.

Comment: Спасибо!)))))))

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понимаю, тире возможно, но не обязательно. Я бы без него обошелся. Хотя надо контекст смотреть.

Comment: какой полезный сервис!)))Спасибо! А здесь нужно тире поставить перед словом "есть"? "значение для испытуемого есть предметное значение для его деятельности".

Comment: Вот здесь тире не нужно. Перед "есть" тире не ставится, в отличие от "это".

Comment: Да согласен, здесь не нужно. Только вопросы задавайте не в комментариях, а отдельной темой. Здесь это за флуд не считается, наоборот, всячески приветствуется.

Comment: Но НЕ обязательно?!.

Comment: @Morkovkin Да. Спасибо.